# Linux command on Windows produces rather unusual behavior

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, git

I have 4 text files, each with about 17 million rows (or lines, if you will). The files are named 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and 4.txt. Text file 1.txt contains the following sample data;

```
0,0:
1,0:
2,0:
3,0:
```

Just a pair of numbers separated by a comma and a colon at the end. Text file 2.txt contains the following sample data;

```
(0,0,0)
(0,0,257)
(0,0,514)
```

Just groups of three numbers separated by commas with the opening and closing brackets at the begining and end. Text file 3.txt contains the following sample data;

```
#000000
#000001
#000002
```

Just 6-character hexadecimal numbers with a pound sign at the start. Lastly, text file 4.txt contains the following sample data;

```
srgb(0,0,0)
srgb(0,0,1)
srgb(0,0,2)
```

What I've been trying to do is combine all the four text files into one, separated by tabs. Output should be like this;

```
0,0:    (0,0,0)     #000000     srgb(0,0,0)
1,0:    (0,0,257)   #000001     srgb(0,0,1)
2,0:    (0,0,514)   #000002     srgb(0,0,2)
3,0:    (0,0,771)   #000003     srgb(0,0,3)
```

I have tried

```
paste -d "\t" 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt> final.txt
```

but i get some weird result, a sample of which looks like

```
0,0:    (0,0,0)     #000000
    srgb(0,0,0)
1,0:    (0,0,257)   #000001
    srgb(0,0,1)
2,0:    (0,0,514)   #000002
    srgb(0,0,2)
3,0:    (0,0,771)   #000003
    srgb(0,0,3)
```

The problem is that the fourth column jumps over a new line which is unexpected for me. Any solutions to fix this? I am on Windows 8.1 and I have Git installed to run Linux commands.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes `3.txt` has no commas whatsoever so I guess it's different than the others. Is that a problem? As to how I examined `final.txt`, I have the  `EmEditor` text file reader installed, which is able to open really large text files

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I forgot to mention that the lines in `3.txt` don't end in any special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *guess* is `3.txt` (and maybe `4.txt`) uses `CR`+`LF` [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) (DOS/Windows style), the other files use sole `LF` (Unix style). `paste` expects lines ended with `LF`, it treats `CR` as a regular character. In effect you got `CR` in the middle of each expected line of the output.

Some text editors are flexible, they go to the next line after detecting `CR`+`LF`, sole `CR` or sole `LF`. This way the excessive `CR` characters generate additional lines when you examine the file: in the sample instead of four lines you see eight. Many Linux tools will still perceive four lines there.

In Linux `file *.txt` would inform you about foreign line endings; `dos2unix 3.txt` would fix them.

The reason one of the files contains `CR`+`LF` may be you generated it with some Windows tool, the file came from the Windows world.

Also note POSIX requires all lines to end with `LF`, while in Windows (I think) the last line may not end with `CR`+`LF`. I know `dos2unix` doesn't add the missing `LF` at the very end (other converters may). Incomplete last line may make Linux tools complain or "misbehave" (e.g. ignore the line). Opening the file in a Linux text editor *and saving* may fix it; in general this depends on the editor and its configuration though.

Comment: Indeed, `3.txt` was generated by a windows tool and all the files are from a windows environment. Running `dos2unix` on all the text files and then running the desired `paste` command surely fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh, and I didn't have any issue at all with the last line(s).